# Не выполняется запрос к БД через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, openserver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Привет)Никак не могу понять почему не выполняется запрос,сама суть что этот пример запроса взят с учебника по php.В браузере пишет Ошибка при выполнении запроса к БД. Вот код
    `

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('***', '***', '***', '***')
or die ('ошибка соединения');
$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, " .
"when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description, " . 
"what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) " . "
VALUES ($first_name, $last_name, $when_it_happened, $how_long, $how_many, " .
"$alien_description, $what_they_did, " .
" $fang_spotted, $dop_inf , $email) ";
$result =mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die ('Ошибка при выполнении запроса к БД.');
mysqli_close($dbc);`
```

Comment: удали `or die ('Ошибка при выполнении запроса к БД.')` и кинь скриншот что будет

Comment: @Alex78191 она ответить не сможет ...

Comment: если убрать or die то он всё  равно не работает,в БД ничего не появляется

Comment: @МаксимЛенский почему не сможет?

Comment: @Вика выложи скриншот ошибки, которая выводится.

Comment: @Alex78191  один балл у неё .. комментить не сможет

Comment: @МаксимЛенский под своим вопросом можно

Comment: Я не знаю как скрин вставить. Ну он выводит те данные что я в форму заносила и в конце пишет : Ошибка при выполнении запроса к БД(в браузере)

Comment: @Вика `or die ('Ошибка при выполнении запроса к БД.');` Это удалить из скрипта нужно и сохранить файл. Тогда должно другую ошибку писать

Comment: удаляла и сохраняла,запрос всё равно не работает

Comment: @Вика какая структура таблицы?

Comment: @Вика вы вывести с базы хотите или записать в базу ?insert это запись - не работает ?

Comment: varchar(30) utf8_bin

Comment: добавить запись

Comment: @Вика локальный сервер или удалённый ? вы на компе пишите или на удалённом сервере ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский `mysqli_connect` сработал же

Comment: на удаленном   сервере

Comment: @Вика вам поучится бы на локалке ... на удалёнке это дольше , на локалке удобнее ..

Comment: спасибо,перенастрою

Answer (score 3):

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('***', '***', '***', '***');

if(!$dbc) {
    echo mysqli_connect_errno() . ":" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// используйте _errno() и _error() при проверке соединения и выполнения запроса.

// Перед подстановкой в запрос не забудьте обработать данные:
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$first_name);
// и т.д.

$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, 
    when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description,
    what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)
    VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long',
        '$how_many', '$alien_description', '$what_they_did',  
        '$fang_spotted', '$dop_inf' , '$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if(!$result) {
    echo mysqli_connect_errno() . ":" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

[mysqli_real_escape_string](https://php.ru/manual/mysqli.real-escape-string.html)

Comment: всё равно не добавляет запись в таблицу в phpmyadmin. может это у меня в настройках что то не так стоит...я уже не знаю просто

Comment: @Вика ошибку какую пишет?

Comment: @Alex78191 вот именно что никакую ошибку не пишет,просто не добавляет данные в таблицу и всё

Comment: @Вика обновил в ответе: вместо die используйте проверку возвращаемого значения через if. Так же ОЧЕНЬ может быть, что по ходу исполнения кода процедура подключения и запроса просто не выполняется по причине какого-нибудь условия.

Comment: @Вика так же проверьте такой вариант подстановки переменных в VALUES :  '" . $first_name . "','" . $last_name . "', etc.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin самое интересное почему нету id ?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Чем от die отличается?

Comment: @Alex78191 считаю проверку через if более взвешенной, вариативность логики и всё такое.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Результат одинаковый будет?

Comment: спасибо,но добавление так и не происходит...увы

Comment: @Вика а какое событие у вас приводит к записи в бд?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin никакого события не происходит. В таблице ни одно поле не заполняется

Comment: у меня есть форма при заполнении которой данные в ней должны переходить и заполняться в таблице php my admin

Comment: @Вика форма сабмитит нормально?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin если честно не совсем поняла о чем вы. А вообще форма правильно прописана с учебника по которому я изучаю